# Ignore escape characters when printing string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I just wrote a simple shell script to save a LaTeX expression as a PNG file. It works fine, except for the LaTeX-syntax for "next row", i.e. the double backslash \\.

When for instance my input expression is like this:

```
\left( \begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{array} \right)
```

The double backslash is reduced to a single one. I know I can add more backslashes in my expression, but I want those expressions to be genuine LaTeX, not some weird LaTeX-bash combination.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo -e "Er moeten twee argumenten worden opgegeven:\n(1) LaTeX code\n(2) Bestandsnaam zonder extensie"
else
    SaveDir="/home/pieter"
    echo "\documentclass{article}\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}\pagestyle{empty}\begin{document}\[ $1 \]\end{document}" > /tmp/$2.tex
    latex -output-directory /tmp -interaction=batchmode $2.tex
    dvips -o /tmp/$2.ps -E /tmp/$2.dvi
    convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 200 /tmp/$2.ps -trim $SaveDir/$2.png
fi
```

So, how can I ignore the escape characters and literally print my LaTeX expression? Preferably without using sed.

Comment: I realised I didn't translate the Dutch phrases. When calling the script you have to give two arguments: the LaTeX expression itself and the filename, without extension. For instance:

**sh .LaTeX2PNG.sh "B_n(f;x) = \sum_{r=0}^n f \left( \frac{r}{n} \right) {n \choose r}  x^r (1-x)^{n-r}" Bernstein**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the TeX you want to output is fixed in your script, the safest is to use something like this:

```
cat > $2.tex << 'ENDHEADER'
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[
ENDHEADER
echo $1 >> $2.tex
cat >> $2.tex << 'ENDFOOTER'
\]
\end{document}
ENDFOOTER
```

The data between the `cat` and `END` markers will be output as is with no substitutions. (I'm assuming all the newlines added are ok.)

Make sure you use hard quotes (`'`) when you pass your TeX as an argument:

```
./your_script '\left( \begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{array} \right)'
```

Comment: Ah of course, the single (hard) quotes! Thank you. I didn't know about the **cat** -construction, why is it safer than the **echo** command?

Comment: Because you can write your TeX without having to worry about the shell munging it.

Comment: Good point, and because of this construction it looks clearer, using the newlines and indentation.

Answer (score 8):

All characters are interpreted literally between single quotes. You used double quotes, and some characters (`` $"\` ``) are interpreted between double quotes. See
[What is the significance of single and double quotes in environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/what-is-the-significance-of-single-and-double-quotes-in-environment-variables) The example in your question happens to never use problematic characters, though. Further potential issues that you avert are using `echo` (the `echo` built-in performs backslash expansion in some shells, but not in bash unless you explicitly enable it), and a lack of double quotes around `$1` (`echo $1` would perform backslash expansion; `echo "$1"` doesn't, in bash).

A safe, portable way to print a string literally is

```
printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

Remove `\n` if you don't want a newline after the string.

Is this your real code? If it is, make sure that the problem isn't in the way you're passing the arguments — you should write something like

```
myscript '\left( \begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{array} \right)' filename
```

If you need a single quote inside the TeX snippet, you'll have to escape it: `'\''`.

You may be interested in the [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) construct, which would allow you to conveniently have a multiline string in your source file. Or you can include a multiline string in single quotes.

```
printf '%s' '\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[ '"$1"' \]
\end{document}
' >"/tmp/$2.tex"
```

Note that you should use double quotes around `$2` too. Always use double quotes around a variable substitution, unless you have a good reason not to.