# Read and confirm shell script before piping from curl to sh (curl -s [url] | sh)

Tags: bash, command-line, security, curl

Whenever I have to execute a shell script from the web `curl -s [url] | sh`, I first open `url` in my web browser to make sure the script isn't malicious and is safe to run.

I remember seeing a command line trick that made it was possible to read the script from the command line and then confirm execution after reading the script. If I recall correctly, it looked something like `curl -s [url] | something...here | sh` and didn't require any software install.

Does anyone know this trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a utility in `moreutils` called `vipe` that shows stdin in an editor, where you can revew and modify the file before it gets passed on to stdout.

If you don't want to install `moreutils`, you can accomplish something similar like so:

```
file=$(mktemp); curl -s "$url" > $file; $EDITOR $file; sh $file; rm $file
```

`mktemp` is in `coreutils` and is very likely already installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to imagine why you would even want to do this, let alone where you would find a source (or sources) of scripts to download and run like this frequently enough that it needs a special-purpose tool.

Why not just download the script with `curl` (or `wget` or `snarf` or whatever), examine and edit it (it's a rare script that wont need some customisation for your particular system) and then run it - either by making it executable with `chmod` or with `sh scriptname`?

Comment: I don't want a special-purpose tool. I remember there was an easy way to do this with standard tools.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to write a small shell script (probably only 5 or so lines) to download a script, present it for viewing with `less` or something, and then ask you if you wanted to run it.  I can't see that that would be any better than just downloading the script, viewing it, and then running it if it seemed OK. IMO it would be worse, it wouldn't offer any advantage but would remove the flexibility you get from just working in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a single utility that would do what you describe, but it's easy enough to make that a shell snippet.

```
script=$(curl -s "$url")
printf "%s\nDo you want to run this script? [yN]" "$script"
read line
case $line in
  [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss]) sh -c "$script";;
esac
```

This assumes the script is a text file. Null bytes are not supported: depending on the shell, they may be removed, or they may cause a line or the whole file to be truncated. Also all newlines at the end of the file are removed (the heredoc construct adds one back). This is not normally a problem for a script, but it could be, for example, if the script ends with an archive in binary format which it extracts. This is not a very reliable way of distributing a file as there is a significant risk of such a binary script to be misencoded at some point. Nonetheless, you can handle it by writing the script to a temporary file.

```
script_file=$(mktemp)
curl -s "$url" | tee "$script_file"
printf "Do you want to run this script? [yN]"
read line
case $line in
  [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss]) sh "$script_file";;
esac
rm "$script_file"
```

Comment: `$()` should be quoted on the first line. Also, this would remove NUL characters in the input, which might conceivably be fatal (for example in the case of a self-extracting script).

Comment: @l0b0 [You don't need to quote in an assignment, though it's arguably good style](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/what-is-the-significance-of-single-and-double-quotes-in-environment-variables/16305#16305). Null bytes are indeed lost, as are final newlines; if you're going to include an archive in a shell script, I recommend using a text encoding such as base64.

Comment: All valid points, as usual. +1

Comment: @l0b0 On second thoughts, while it's somewhat risk-prone, this is a valid use case. I've updated my answer. I've also corrected a defect in my original answer which didn't allow the script to use its stdin (because the script was passed on stdin, for no good reason).

Answer (score 0):

Use this command line:

```
curl URL | ( cat > /tmp/file; read REPLY; [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && cat /tmp/file ) | sh
```

You could use a small function for that:

```
curlsh()
{
    curl "$1" \
    | ( cat > /tmp/file;read REPLY; [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && cat /tmp/file ) \
    | sh
}
```

And than use it this way:

```
curlsh http://site.in.net/path/to/script
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your **read** knows -p (prompt), and the script needn't be executed with the interpreter, specified by the shebang:

```
curl URL | tee /tmp/x && read -p "execute?" key ; test $key = y && sh /tmp/x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just type in the command without piping it.

I ran a similar script that pipes to bash, but removing the pipe so it is just curl and the URL, the file shows in the terminal as if I had just ran a cat command.

For instance, this command:

```
curl https://get.pimoroni.com/pantilthat | bash
```

Gave me this result:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 38706  100 38706    0     0  47087      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47087

This script will install everything needed to use
Pan-Tilt HAT

Always be careful when running scripts and commands copied
from the internet. Ensure they are from a trusted source.

If you want to see what this script does before running it,
you should run: 'curl https://get.pimoroni.com/pantilthat'

Note: Pan-Tilt HAT requires I2C communication

Do you wish to continue? [y/N]
```

And running the following allowed me to view the file in my terminal:

```
curl https://get.pimoroni.com/pantilthat
```

I know its been almost 9 years, but I hope that helps you or anyone else who may have the same question!

Comment: @AdminBee Apart from downloading the script twice (first to look at it and then to run it), this answer answers the question with a simple and accessible workflow.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was under the impression that avoiding a manual two-pass approach was the core of the question. I may be mistaken, though, and I agree that not having to open a web browser is already an improvement. (Note that it was not me who downvoted the answer).