# Script with variable in path

Tags: shell-script, quoting, variable

I'm not entirely sure where to ask or how to formulate this question with correct terminology.

I have script here for managing a game (minecraft) server for the user (bukkit).
I've cut out some variables and **I want to know why this is not working and a possible solution**.

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/bukkit

USERNAME='bukkit'
MCROOT='/home/$USERNAME' 
MCPATH='/home/$USERNAME/Server'
BACKUPPATH='/home/$USERNAME/backups'
SCRIPTLOG='/home/$USERNAME/script.log'
LOGPATH='/home/$USERNAME/Server/logs'

(line 50) cd $MCPATH
```

(I also like to have $MCROOT in the paths followed by it.)

Running the script gives:

```
/bin/bukkit: line 50: cd: /home/$USERNAME/Server: No such file or directory
-su: line 0: cd: /home//Server: No such file or directory
```

The point is to have different USERNAME in different files and I thought I'd save time editing all paths be replacing everything with one variable normally in the rest of the code.
So my other file called "ftb" has `USERNAME='ftb'`

```
"/bin/bukkit" is a symbolic link to "/etc/init.d/bukkit"
```

*Have a nice day!*

Comment: Don't hate, just guide my poor soul.

Comment: @ekaj Yes, the directory /home/bukkit/Server exists.

Comment: @ekaj hmm, I'll test it.

Comment: Variables don't get expanded inside single quotes, hence the system is looking for literal `/home/$USERNAME/Server` instead of `/home/bukkit/Server`. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: You can also just not use quotes and do `MCPATH=/home/$USERNAME/Server`

Comment: True, I don't use a whole lot of spaces in my paths...

Comment: @steeldriver You should probably post that as an answer

Comment: @ekaj apologies - I was sure there had to be a duplicate, but I can't find an exact one one so I have added an answer here with a link to a "near dupe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't get expanded inside single quotes, hence the system is looking for literal `/home/$USERNAME/Server` instead of `/home/bukkit/Server`.

Your code should work if you use double quotes instead e.g.

```
MCPATH="/home/$USERNAME/Server"
```

There is a more detailed discussion at [What is the significance of single and double quotes in environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/what-is-the-significance-of-single-and-double-quotes-in-environment-variables)