# Why can I not extract the first word (size) from output of "du" command with ${xx%% *}?

Tags: shell

I just wanted to write a script and needed to extract the size of directories. There I discovered a strange effect which I don't understand:

I used the "du" command:

```
> x=$(du mydir)
> echo $x
8192 mydir
```

So far ok. But now I want to extract the size by removing all chars from **x** beginning with the first whitespace. But then I get

```
> echo ${x%% *}
8192 mydir
```

instead of just 8192.

So checked that with another variable, not generated by "du"

```
> y="8192 mydir"
> echo ${y%% *}
8192
```

Why does this work for **y** but not for **x**?
I also checked that **x** and **y** are identical strings.

I'm really puzzled here. I will be very pleased if anybody has an answer for that?

Comment: I suspect that `x` and `y` are **not** identical strings - the `du` output is actually tab separated, and only looks like a space when you do `echo $x` because the unquoted `$x` is subject to word splitting by the shell. See for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Welcome, you can use an array instead: `a=($(du adir); echo "a[0]"`.

Comment: To create an indexed array you should do `a=($(du adir))` -- note the additional parenthesis. To extract the number you can do `echo ${a[0]}` or even `echo $a`

Answer (score 5):

If you double-quote your variable you'll see that there's visibly more than one space. In actual fact it's a tab character, which you can see on some systems more clearly with

```
echo "$x" | cat -e
```

You can therefore match the tab (or space) with this construct, which removes the longest sequence of "*space-or-tab followed by anything*" that's bound to the end of the string value in `$x`

```
echo "${x%%[[:blank:]]*}"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks thats' it! I didn't realize that $x is not the same as "$x"!

Comment: @Humpri, see [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/100397) and also [What is the significance of single and double quotes in environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16303/100397)

Answer (score 2):

`xxd` or `hd` are good tools for investigating such things. Example:

```bsh
$ du sample
32  sample

$ du sample | xxd -g 1
00000000: 33 32 09 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 0a        32.sample.
```

If your hex notation is rusty you can use `ascii`:

```
$ ascii -x
   00 NUL    10 DLE    20      30 0    40 @    50 P    60 `    70 p 
   01 SOH    11 DC1    21 !    31 1    41 A    51 Q    61 a    71 q 
   02 STX    12 DC2    22 "    32 2    42 B    52 R    62 b    72 r 
   03 ETX    13 DC3    23 #    33 3    43 C    53 S    63 c    73 s 
   04 EOT    14 DC4    24 $    34 4    44 D    54 T    64 d    74 t 
   05 ENQ    15 NAK    25 %    35 5    45 E    55 U    65 e    75 u 
   06 ACK    16 SYN    26 &    36 6    46 F    56 V    66 f    76 v 
   07 BEL    17 ETB    27 '    37 7    47 G    57 W    67 g    77 w 
   08 BS     18 CAN    28 (    38 8    48 H    58 X    68 h    78 x 
   09 HT     19 EM     29 )    39 9    49 I    59 Y    69 i    79 y 
   0A LF     1A SUB    2A *    3A :    4A J    5A Z    6A j    7A z 
   0B VT     1B ESC    2B +    3B ;    4B K    5B [    6B k    7B { 
   0C FF     1C FS     2C ,    3C <    4C L    5C \    6C l    7C | 
   0D CR     1D GS     2D -    3D =    4D M    5D ]    6D m    7D } 
   0E SO     1E RS     2E .    3E >    4E N    5E ^    6E n    7E ~
```

From this you quickly find:

- 33 => 3
- 32 => 2
- 09 => HT, or Horizontal Tab
- 73 => s
- ...

In other words. `32<HT>sample`. Space is 0x20 and you would have gotten `33 32 20 73 ...` if that was the case.

Another tool is `od`, here using the `-c` option, (`-a` or `-ac` can also be nice):

```
$ printf %s "$x" | od -c
0000000   3   2  \t   s   a   m   p   l   e
```

Which also gives you the actual contents – when you quote correctly.

Solution is to use [@roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631924/140633)s example or something in the line of

```bsh
$ read -r size name<<< $(du sample)
$ echo "$size"
32
```

---

All depending on what you want `awk` is also likely a good candidate.